# converges in $L^p(R)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the sequence of functions
\begin{align}
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n}\quad  if\quad x\in [0,n]\\
0 \quad \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
(1)Prove that $f_n\rightarrow0$ strongly in every space $L^p(
\mathbf{R})$ with $1<p\leq\infty$.
(2)On the other hand, show that in the space $L^1(\mathbf{R})$ this sequence is not strongly convergent.

I really don't know how to prove for this question.

Comment: $\|f_n\|_p=\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{n^p}dx\right)^{1/p}=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$ for all $1\le p$, which contradicts (2).

Comment: sorry~~~it has mistake, x is in $[0, n]$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\|f_n\|_p=\left(\int_0^n\frac{1}{n^p}dx\right)^{1/p}=\frac{1}{n}n^{1/p}=\frac{1}{n^{1-1/p}}$

But

$\dfrac{1}{n^{1-1/p}}\to\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}0&if&1<p<\infty\\1&if&p=1\end{array}\right.$

Moreover, if $p=\infty$, then $\|f_n\|_\infty=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$. This proves (1).

Now, suppose let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, $n>m$. Then $\|f_n-f_m|\|_1=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\frac{1}{m}1_{[1,m]}-\frac{1}{n}1_{[1,n]}|dx=\int_0^m\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}dx+\int_m^n\frac{1}{n}dx=2$. Then  $\{f_n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence. As $L^1$ is a complete metric space (Banach space), then $\{f_n\}$ is not convergent.